# Can I catch resizing of the window (entering to multi window mode), when I use Multi Window feature?

Tags: android

I implement my application which uses multi window feature. What I want is to know, can I catch the entering to the multi window mode? Are there any listeners for it?

Comment: as your question is very old and i think you required to get callback for other devices which has custom feature of multi-window .But for Android-n i can give suggestion  to check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36098551/1140237

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is currently a listener for multi-window mode.

What I would try to do is to add a Callback to the window, and detect when the window size is changed (through onWindowAttributesChanged).