# How to change view for multiple window display in Android N? How to check application is in multiwindow or not?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-7.0-nougat, android-n-preview

How can we give separate layout or separate activity for Multiple window ?

eg. I have checked below things with help of android developer site

```
<activity android:name="com.configure.it.MyScreen">
    <layout android:defaultHeight="400dp"
          android:defaultWidth="200dp"
          android:gravity="top|end"
          android:minimalSize="300dp" />
</activity>
```

by declaring above things it affect how an activity behaves in multi-window mode.

But how can I show different layout if my particular screen is activated on Multiple-Window ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Android Developer link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html#running) .

To make changes in UI or separate layout which should be used on Multiple-window activate.

We can check if activity is in Multiple-window by following way

- ***From activity `Activity.isInMultiWindowMode()` Call to find out if the activity is in multi-window mode.***

eg. To check in Activity if its multiple window than header(or any view should have Red background color if its not in multiple window thn it should be Green background color)

```
headerView.setBackgroundColor(inMultiWindow()?Color.RED:Color.GREEN);
```

using `inMultiWindow()` replacing **Fragment** is also possible

- ***To get Callback on Multiple-Window Activation.***

From Activity `onMultiWindowChanged` method is available to handle runtime changes on this method callback.System will give callback on this method whenever the activity goes into or out of multi-window mode with `boolean` value.With the help of [sample link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MultiWindowPlayground/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/android/multiwindowplayground/activities/LoggingActivity.java) & android developer link

```
@Override
public void onMultiWindowChanged(boolean inMultiWindow) {
    super.onMultiWindowChanged(inMultiWindow);
    headerView.setBackgroundColor(inMultiWindow ? Color.RED : Color.GREEN);
    // here we can change entire fragment also.
    //If multiple window in than seperate and for multiple window out different

}
```

Will keep updating if I get anything else.

Comment: New name of this function is `isInMultiWindowMode()`

Comment: Should be `onMultiWindowModeChanged` not `onMultiWindowChanged`

Answer (score 1):

**isInMultiWindowMode()** is added in API 24 to check device is in Multi window Mode or not, it returns a boolean value. whenever device goes to Multi window Mode it triggers `onConfigurationChanged()` method.

you will need to manually ***update your Views, Reload resources, etc...*** in  onConfigurationChanged() based on Landscape and portrait mode.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
     if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
      {
        //do something (Update your views / Reload resources)
      }else{

      }
}
```

In Manifest.xml

```
 <activity
   android:name=".yourActivity"
   android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation"
 />
```

For further reference check with [Multi-Window Support Google Dev](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html) and [MultiWindow Medium Corp](https://medium.com/google-developers/5-tips-for-preparing-for-multi-window-in-android-n-7bed803dda64)